# Yii2-editable-widget. Doesn't work with few widgets

Tags: yii2

I'm using editable widget (2amigos/yii2-editable-widget or kartik-v/yii2-editable). It works fine, but when I try it in foreach it works with first element only. I want to use a several widgets for a model. How can I solve it?

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($models as $model) {
    echo Editable::widget( [
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'url' => 'site/rename',
        'type' => 'text',
        'mode' => 'pop',
        'clientOptions' => [
'            pk' => $model->id,
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have to set a unique id for each Editable Widget. Look how the js code for the widget is embedded.

e.g. if you use kartiks widget

```
 echo Editable::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'name',
    'type' => 'primary',
    'size'=> 'lg',
    'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
    'editableValueOptions' => ['class' => 'text-success h3'],
    'options'=> [
        'id'=>'name-editable'.uniqid(),
    ]
]);
```